# How to change (USD) to (RS) on advanced search page.

Tags: magento-1.9, currency, advanced-search

I am building an ecommerce magento website name [www.bookslab.in](http://www.bookslab.in). I want to change the (USD) on advanced search tab to "(RS)" as i am selling the books only in india, so i need the indian currency which is Rupees(RS). I had attached an screenshot of advanced search page. Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: change your currency in admin

Comment: I had already changed it in admin panel. My all prices are in indian rupees excluding this text (USD) it is not currency it is an just the text

Comment: have you clear the cache?

Comment: @Meenakshi my site is working fine & i am not having any problem in currency . I just want to change this (USD) text to (RS) that i attached the screenshot above

Comment: any answer stacky's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This text is usually looked up from session or config. So try the following:

1. clear your cookies and see if it's working. otherwise continue below.
2. `system > configuration > general > currency setup > currency options`

   - set `base currency` and `default display currency` to *Indian Rupee*
   - make sure *Indian Rupee* is selected under `allowed currencies`
3. flush all caches